# Show SQL executed per request in ASP.NET MVC using LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, profiling

Is it possible to show the SQL that was executed for a particular request in an ASP.NET MVC app?  I would like to show how many queries, and what they were on the bottom of pages during debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to include it on the page, you can [implement an Action Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056.aspx) that logs the SQL output by using the `Log` property on the Data Context, and then in `OnResultExecuted` injects the SQL output into the View Data.

Comment: I think that will do exactly what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to update this question with the code once you're done! =] The tricky part feels like getting at the Data Context from the Action Filter, so that you can start logging precisely in `OnActionExecuting` and stop precisely in `OnResultExecuted`.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ to SQL `DataContext` class has a [`Log` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) that you can use to obtain the generated SQL statement for the executes queries. To display the statement while debugging, see for example this: http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Kris/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the Log property existed!